# linear transformation that Im(T)=Ker(T)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(x,y)=(2x-3y,\alpha  x+\beta y)$ and $Ker(T)=Im(T)$
>
> find $\alpha,\beta$

How should I approach this?

Comment: I'm haven't solved this one in particular, but another example where $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{Ker}(T)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where you first project onto the $y$ axis and then rotate down to the $x$-axis.

Comment: $T^2(x,y)$ must be $0$ for all $x,y$, as this is $T(T(x,y))$. and $T(x,y)$ is in $Ker(T)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $T(1,0)=(2,\alpha)$ and $T(0,1)=(-3,\beta)$ belong to $\operatorname{Im} T$. Thus they also belong to $\operatorname{Ker} T$.

What can you deduce from the fact that $T(2,\alpha)=(0,0)$? Similarly, can you say something about $\beta$ from $T(-3,\beta)=(0,0)$?